# SQL - query multiplying records returned - Cartesian Product

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query which is returning a huge number of multiplied records - i.e. a cartesian product:

```
SELECT * FROM specimen, topography_index, morphology, functions 
WHERE 
SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code 
AND 
if(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, functions.functions_code = specimen.snop_code) 
AND 
specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
ORDER BY 
(specimen.room = 'f') DESC,specimen.snop_code
```

The number of records being returned is around 59,000.  However, specimen table only has 469 records.  The morphology and functions tables have around 2000 records each, and the topography_index table has 29 records, so I'm guessing that the results are being multiplied by the number of records in 'topography_index' and 'morphology' or 'functions' tables (29 x 2000), whichever one that doesn't have a join in the if clause.

How should the query be written so that this doesn't happen?

Note that GROUP BY is NOT an option as the query is so slow with all the records being returned.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bda8/1

Perhaps this could be handled by a sub select statement?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try using an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cartesian product should be the product of # of rows in properly joined tables times the rows in tables that are not properly joined (i.e. don't have effective condition in the `WHERE` clause). For cases where `specimen.snop_axis = 'M'` morphology and specimen are propely joined but functions isn't, and when `specimen.snop_axis <> 'M'` functions and specimen are properly joined but morphology isn't. That's most likely why the resulting number of rows doesn't seem to be any direct product of rows in the tables.

To solve this I'd first try to join all the tables properly by replacing

```
AND if(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, functions.functions_code = specimen.snop_code)
```

with

```
AND functions.functions_code = specimen.snop_code
AND morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
```

To me, this seems to give ok result with the sample data, but I wouldn't be too sure of how it behaves with your real data.

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to obtain by having that `IF` condition in `WHERE` clause. If the objective is to return morphology data and no functions data when `specimen.snop_axis='M'` and in other cases to return functions data and no morphology data, I'd suggest having the selection logic applied in the columns that are returned, somehow like this:

```
SELECT
IF(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology_pk, functions_pk) matching_pk,
IF(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology_code, functions_code) matching_code,
IF(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology_nomen, functions_nomen) matching_nomen,
specimen.*,
topography_index.*
```

instead of just having columns from both tables returned always. But as I said, I'm not quite sure I understand what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Cartesian product of two tables multiplies every row with every other row which should not happen.I would explain this using  [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm).

You can see that result is somewhat undesired as some of the tuples are giving false information.

So, in  order to prevent this and make it work the way we want, instead of writing:

```
SELECT  ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
 FROM CUSTOMERS, ORDERS;
```

we should write:

```
SELECT  ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
 FROM CUSTOMERS, ORDERS WHERE ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID=CUSTOMERS.ID;
```

Hope you got the idea about what you need to do in order to get correct output.